# How to update a view in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have create view without any problem in Oracle. But I can not update it.I want update view in oracle, please help.  Is it possible anyway?

Comment: Some views allow their underlying tables to be updated, but the views must satisfy certain conditions. See the [11g documentation on views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF54684) (look for the section titled "Notes on Updatable Views"). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `instead of` trigger on the view, [as described in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG52800):

> A view presents the output of a query as a table. If you want to change a view as you would change a table, you must create `INSTEAD OF` triggers. Instead of changing the view, they change the underlying tables.

Once you have that trigger in place, you can update the view using the same syntax as if it was a table.

You haven't shown your view or table definitions so there isn't enough information to provide a useful example; fortunately the documentation has one you can use as a starting point.

Comment: As Bob pointed out some views are updatable anyway; but from the question I assumed you'd tried to update and got an error, indicating this view does not fall into that category. I should have mentioned that...

Answer (score 2):

View is a select of your table my friend, there for if you want to update your view you must update your table and then you will see the changes in your view.

Comment: Maybe, but some views *are* updateable. And all views can even be *made* updateable.

Answer (score 0):

update view_name  set  column_name_in_view   = 'value' ;

update  view_name set  column_name_in_view  = 'value' where column_name_in_view = 'value' ;